# C program, designing a check

Tags: c, string

I'm writing a program that basically just takes a bunch of user input and Outputs it in the form of a check. My problem is that I'm entering 2 sentences and while the second one is fine it completly skips the first one! and the user last name is working but the first name just outputs "z" it is the weirdest thing and my teachers philosophy is figure it out yourself. So can anyone possibly help me?? Here is my code...

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
    char date[8];
    int checkNum;
    char payeeFirst[10];
    char payeeLast[10];
    double amount;
    char memo[50];
    char wordAmount[100];
    printf("Please enter the date: ");
    scanf("%s", &date);
    printf("Please enter the check number: ");
    scanf("%d", &checkNum);
    printf("Please enter the payee First name: ");
    scanf("%s", &payeeFirst);
    printf("Please enter payee last name: ");
    scanf("%s", &payeeLast);
    printf("Please enter amount: ");
    scanf("%d", &amount);
    printf("Please enter amount in words: ");
    fgets (wordAmount, sizeof(wordAmount)-1, stdin);
    printf("Please enter memo: ");
    fgets (memo, sizeof(memo)-1, stdin);


    printf("                               \n");
    printf("Date: %s .\n", date);
    printf("Check Number: %d .\n", checkNum);
    printf("Payee: [%s] [%s] .\n", payeeFirst, payeeLast);
    printf("Amount: %d .\n", amount);
    printf("                                 Check %d \n", checkNum);
    printf("                                 Date: %s \n", date);
    printf("Pay to the\n");
    printf("Order of    %s %s   $%d \n", payeeFirst, payeeLast, amount);
    printf("%s", wordAmount);
    printf("                        \n");
    printf("                        \n");
    printf("Memo: %s \n", memo);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I dont think you need the & sign when reading a string into a char[] array.  Should just be scanf("%s", date); etc.  Edit: And by don't need I mean I think its breaking your code.

Comment: If you are using gcc add `-Wall` flag. It will warn you when you use `scanf` incorrectly. Like here: http://ideone.com/oD5F4

Comment: I would also make sure your strings are null terminated.  Perhaps initialize the contents of the arrays to 0;

Comment: You don't need the `-1` in the size argument to `fgets`.

Answer (score 1):

Your `scanf` calls all leave the `'\n'` in the stream (the next `scanf` will ignore it though).

The first `fgets` reads an empty string (well ... a string containing a single `'\n'`).

Try reading the numbers with `fgets` too (to a temporary buffer) and `sscanf` from the buffer to the correct variable. This way all the `'\n'` will be accounted for.